# Environment and Effects UI not refreshing after progress bar update in 3ds Max

Tags: c++, 3dsmax

I have already created a [3ds max forum post](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max-forum/environment-and-effects-ui-not-refreshing-after-progress-bar/td-p/9272321) with this issue but found no luck at all. 
Basically, I was facing the UI freeze issue in 3ds Max after the progress bar update.
This issue can be reproduced with the following steps.

1. Create a sample scene in 3ds Max.
2. Open **[ Environment and Effects ]** window in 3ds Max and select **[Physical Camera Exposure Control ]** and keep it open.
3. Using **[ File ]** > **[ Export ]** > **[ Export ]** menu export the scene to FBX.

   - It is visible that **[ Environment and Effects ]** window is automatically closed when the progress bar is displayed.
   - This window will re-open after completing the FBX export.
4. Check whether Global EV value is editable in **[ Environment and Effects ]** window.

   - In our trial, it is noted that value is not editable.
   - Also UI components under **[ Physical Camera Exposure Control ]** are not editable.
   - Actually value is changed but UI is not refreshed.

It was mostly related to EndEditParams() function as mentioned in [3ds Max 2019 SDK, ProgressStart() function descritpion](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Max-Developer-Help/cpp_ref/class_interface.html?&_ga=2.200392302.1979062684.1592393271-430933839.1579263115#afc299d1d68a64607ddc8e582c62b877b) .

Is there any way to fix this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the link to your forum post here since the answers/exchange in there might be useful for others.

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max-forum/environment-and-effects-ui-not-refreshing-after-progress-bar/m-p/9587577

From what I can understand, this is indeed a bug in 3ds Max 2019 that has been fixed in older version (3ds Max 2021).